# Cannot figure out SQL Select statement in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having some trouble understanding WHY a select statement isn't working in a query I'm making.

I've got the `SELECT` and `FROM` lines functioning. With just those, ALL results from my selected table are displayed - 517 or so

What I want to do is display results based on a pattern using LIKE - What I have so far

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl_ServiceRequestMatrix 
WHERE Tbl_ServiceRequestMatrix.[Application/Form] LIKE 'P%';
```

This returns 0 results - despite the fact that the column selected DOES have entries that start with 'P'

I also tried utilising brackets, see if that was the issue - still displays 0 results:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Tbl_ServiceRequestMatrix
WHERE ((Tbl_ServiceRequestMatrix.[Application/Form])='p%');
```

Can any one help me understand why my `WHERE ** LIKE` statement is causing 0 results to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard character in MS Access is (by default) `*` instead of `%`:

```
WHERE Tbl_ServiceRequestMatrix.[Application/Form] LIKE "P*"
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that :/ I thought using SQL the syntax would be the same for wildcard chars. 
Any ways, I have just tried using ' * ' as the wildcard - Still gives me 0 results :(
@Tedo G. - Thanks dude - Doesn't work though

Comment: Terribly sorry guys! I accidentally deleted 'LIKE' from my statement without realizing!! The asterisk is the right character and does display the results correctly, I apologize for my stupidity in deleting part of my statement :P

I'll mark this as answered in a while - But do either of you know if it's possible to filter the LIKE definition via a User input box on a form? I know you can't use the select in VBA code as SELECT isn't an action statement and thus causes error in VBA code

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` Statement has different parameters in different `sql` languages.
In MS Access you need `*` Instead of `%` in `LIKE` Statement.